# Sending to multiple recipients with Powershell array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have this powershell script to sending emails, but when I add multiple recipients with a Powershell array, I've got an error:
"send-mailmessage : An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','."
I've read the documentation and still can't figure it out. Thank you.

This is my script:

```
$ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$strTo=''
#---------------------------------------------------------
$arrayList.add("danny.goethals@rousselot.com")
$ArrayList.add("wim.vandekerckhove@rousselot.com")
#---------------------------------------------------------
foreach($Mailadres in $ArrayList)
{
#$strTo='"'+$Mailadres+'"'+','+$strTo
$strTo=$Mailadres+','+$strTo
}
$EmailTo=$strTo.Substring(0,$strTo.Length-1)
$EmailTo -split','
$EmailFrom = “postmaster@darlingii.com”
$Subject = “TEST mail”
$Body = “Test!!" 
$SMTPServer = "192.168.0.42"
send-mailmessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SMTPServer
```

Comment: please add the ENTIRE error msg to your Question. PoSh usually has useful info in those msgs ... [*grin*]

Comment: are these _REAL_ email addresses? If som sanitize the question immediately!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite a mess and you're doing things more complicated than necessary and some things just wrong. For example you are creating a string with comma separated email addresses, not an array. You're not assigning the result of the `-split` operation to anything. And that's exactly what the error message says.

Just create the array like this:

```
$EmailTo = 'danny.goethals@rousselot.com', 'wim.vandekerckhove@rousselot.com'
```

This single line replaces the first 13 lines of your code.

You should also avoid these strange "curly quotes" and only use `"` or `'`.

Comment: OK - I've simplified my code and it works - admittedly not with an array. I did this because I had about 30 email addresses.

Comment: You _are_ using an array. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.1#other-syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
$EmailFrom = “postmaster@darlingii.com”
$Subject = “TEST mail”
$Body = “TEST!" 
$SMTPServer = "192.168.0.42"
$EmailTo=
#===================Production================================
"stijn.dolfen@rousselot.com",
#===================author================================
"danny.goethals@rousselot.com"
#===================PA================================
send-mailmessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SMTPServer $SMTPServer
```